# Dynamic slidbox width css issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app, in which I need to create an ion-slider dynamically. Each ion-slide can only have 5 items max. The next 5 items are added to the next ion-slide. I am a little confused to achieve this. I think it can be all done via CSS, but I am not good at it. It works fine when my array contains only 5 items. If it contains 10, then all of the are crunched together.

Here is what I tried:

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='todo'>

  <ion-pane>
    <ion-content ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div class="button-bar" style="border: 2px solid #00aec9;">
        <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" does-continue="true" ng-repeat="mod in modules">
          <ion-slide>
            <div ng-repeat="item in mod.details" class="footer-bar" align="center">
              {{item.name}}
            </div>
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>

</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.modules = [{
    details: [{
      name: "name 1"

    }, {
      name: "name 2"
    }, {
      name: "name 3"
    }, {
      name: "name 4"
    }, {
      name: "name 5"
    }]
  }, {
    details: [{
      name: "1.1"

    }, {
      name: "2.2"
    }, {
      name: "3.3"
    }, {
      name: "4.4"
    }, {
      name: "5.5"
    }]
  }];
});
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-slide
{
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/TILgeHZ4hkHHghn8GvbB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try style="float:left"

```
<ion-content ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="button-bar" style="border: 2px solid #00aec9;">
        <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" does-continue="true">
            <ion-slide ng-repeat="mod in modules" style="float:left">
                <div ng-repeat="item in mod.details" class="footer-bar" align="center">
                    {{item.name}}
                </div>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: how does that create a new ion-slide for every 5 items? It creates only one slide with 5 items. I need to be able to generate multiple slides with 5 items each. See my plunker.

Comment: one by one in new line??

Comment: ion-slide is outside the any loop. To create a new ion-slide it should be inside, right?

Comment: if you use ng-repeat in ion-slide it will create slide one above to other

Comment: Ok. But with your logic it still generates just a single slide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92172/discussion-between-skone-and-paresh-gami).